# How to make chapters start on odd pages with a picture on the even page

Tags: formatting, chapters

I'm using a template based on the book-class for my thesis. All Chapter titles are nicely formated and start on odd pages. 
What I would like is to have a picture to the left of each title page.

The whole .cls is at the bottom (it is a bit of a mess because I have been editing...)

Here are some relevant parts

```
%% A part title starts with a huge (96pt) bold black number, flushed to the
%% right, followed by the part name on the next line in the title color.
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thepart}
    {0pt}
    {\huge\color{title}}
%% Separate the title from the text by two empty lines.
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
%% Chapter titles have the same layout as parts.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\flushleft\Huge\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
```

And

```
%% Remove the header and page number on empty pages.
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@twoside%
        \ifodd\c@page%
            \newpage%
        \else%
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \vspace*{\fill}%
            \newpage%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}
```

Whole .cls file

```
%%%%
% Some commands have been commented out using %FASTLOAD%  . In hope of speeding up the refreshing of the preview


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dissertation}[2013/07/08 v1.0 TU Delft dissertation class]

\newif\if@nativefonts
\DeclareOption{nativefonts}{\@nativefontstrue}
\newif\if@print
\DeclareOption{print}{\@printtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\RequirePackage{type1cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{longtable}
\RequirePackage[countmax]{subfloat} 
\RequirePackage{makecell}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage{placeins}

%% English is the default language, but Dutch is used for some sections.
\RequirePackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[nooneline,footnotesize]{caption}
%\RequirePackage{chapterbib}
\RequirePackage{etaremune}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,hang]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
\RequirePackage{pdflscape}
%\RequirePackage{bibentry}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt} 
\ifxetex
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{geometry}
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{graphicx}
    \RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{xltxtra}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\else
    \ifpdf
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{geometry}
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
    \else
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{geometry}
        \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}
        \RequirePackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
    \fi
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{metalogo}

\RequirePackage{sidecap}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
%\RequirePackage{e-TEX}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}% — available from CTAN (required)
\RequirePackage{keyval}% — a standard package (required)
\RequirePackage{ifthen}% — a standard package (required)
\RequirePackage{url}%  — a standard package (required)
\RequirePackage[natbib, authordate,backend=biber,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false, uniquename=false,
ibidtracker=false,sortcites,noibid]{biblatex-chicago}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


%% If the document is not compiled with XeLaTeX, we need to use the native
%% fonts.
\ifxetex\else
    \@nativefontstrue
\fi


\if@nativefonts
    %% The native font is Utopia Regular with Fourier math. We use Latin Modern
    %% as a fallback, since Utopia lacks support for sans-serif and monospace.
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage{lmodern}
    \RequirePackage{fourier}
    %% The style for titles is small caps.
    \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
    \def\titleshape{\scshape}
    \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \if@print
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \else
        \def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape}
    \fi
\else
    %% The TU Delft house style fonts are Bookman Old Style (serif) for titles
    %% and Tahoma (sans-serif) for text. Apart from these, we use Courier New
    %% for monospace and Cambria for math.
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math}



    %% The default style for text is Perpetua (serif).
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    %% The default style for titles is GILL Sans MT (sans serif).
    \def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
    \def\titleshape{}
    \if@print
        \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
    \else
        \def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape}
    \fi
    \def\headerstyle{\titlestyle}
\fi

         \setsansfont[SmallCapsFont={Gentium Plus}, SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]{Gentium Book Basic}

         \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
         \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

         \setmainfont[
       Path = Fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf]{OverlockSC-Regular}



\newfontfamily\figcapfont{Gentium Book Basic}% Some other font
\DeclareCaptionFormat{figcapfont}{\figcapfont\textbf{#1#2} #3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=figcapfont}
%\newfontfamily{\LETTGentium}{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily{\LETTOverlock}[
       Path = Fonts/,
        Extension = .ttf]{OverlockSC-Regular}


%CHange the font inside tables to small
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}

%% Define the TU Delft house style colors.
\definecolor{tudelft-cyan}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-black}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}
\definecolor{tudelft-white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-sea-green}{cmyk}{0.54,0,0.32,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-green}{cmyk}{1,0.15,0.4,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-dark-blue}{cmyk}{1,0.66,0,0.4}
\definecolor{tudelft-purple}{cmyk}{0.98,1,0,0.35}
\definecolor{tudelft-turquoise}{cmyk}{0.82,0,0.21,0.08}
\definecolor{tudelft-sky-blue}{cmyk}{0.45,0,0.06,0.06}
\definecolor{tudelft-lavendel}{cmyk}{0.45,0.2,0,0.07}
\definecolor{tudelft-orange}{cmyk}{0.02,0.56,0.84,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-warm-purple}{cmyk}{0.58,1,0,0.02}
\definecolor{tudelft-fuchsia}{cmyk}{0.19,1,0,0.19}
\definecolor{tudelft-bright-green}{cmyk}{0.36,0,1,0}
\definecolor{tudelft-yellow}{cmyk}{0.02,0,0.54,0}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{84F61F}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{2E77E2}
\definecolor{yellow}{HTML}{FFDE20}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF9620}
\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{F51F64}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{7D0BF9}
%% Use TU Delft cyan as the color for titles, unless the 'print' option is
%% specified, in which case we use anthracite, a dark gray, which is also used
%% for the thumb indices.
\definecolor{anthracite}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.8}
\definecolor{NOcyan}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.8}

\if@print
    \colorlet{title}{anthracite}
\else
    \colorlet{title}{NOcyan}
\fi
\colorlet{thumb}{anthracite}


%%%%%%%%SETTINGS FOR THESIS SIZE
%% Set the paper size to 17 by 24 cm, approximately halfway between A4 and A5.
%\if@print
    %% In print mode we add a 3 mm bleed on the outside of the page.
    \geometry{
        papersize = {170mm,240mm},
        layoutsize = {167mm,240mm},
        layoutoffset = {3mm,3mm},
        bindingoffset = -3mm
    }
%\else
%    \geometry{papersize={170mm,240mm}}
%\fi

%% We decrease the margins slightly from the default (scale = 0.7).
\geometry{hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8}

%% Redefine the title command to accept an optional subtitle.
\renewcommand*\title[2][]{%
    \def\@subtitle{#1}%
    \def\@title{#2}%
    %% Add the title to the PDF meta data.
    \hypersetup{pdftitle=#2}%
}
%% Citations

%\addbibresource{dissertation.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{
\clearlist{language}
\clearlist{doi}
\clearlist{arxivId}
\clearlist{archivePrefix}
\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{MyPapers}
%\defbibenvironment{ListofPublications}
% {\list
% {}
% {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
%  \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
%  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
%  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
%{\endlist}
%{\item}

%% Redefine the author command to accept a first and last name, and to add the
%% full name to the PDF meta data.
\renewcommand*\author[2]{%
    \def\@firstname{#1}%
    \def\@lastname{#2}%
    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=#1\ #2}%
}
\renewcommand\and{\\[\baselineskip]}


%% Remove the header and page number on empty pages.
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@twoside%
        \ifodd\c@page%
            \newpage%
        \else%
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \vspace*{\fill}%
            \newpage%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}





\if@print%
    \newcommand*\cropmarks{%
        \ifodd\c@page%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \draw ($(current page.north east)+(0mm,-3mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-2mm,-3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.north east)+(-3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.north east)+(-3mm,-2mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south east)+(0mm,3mm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(-2mm,3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south east)+(-3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.south east)+(-3mm,2mm)$);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        \else%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \draw ($(current page.north west)+(0mm,-3mm)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(2mm,-3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.north west)+(3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.north west)+(3mm,-2mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south west)+(0mm,3mm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+(2mm,3mm)$);
                \draw ($(current page.south west)+(3mm,0mm)$) -- ($(current page.south west)+(3mm,2mm)$);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        \fi%
    }
\else
    \newcommand*\cropmarks{}
\fi%

%%% Thumb indices consist of white text on a rectangular colored background. The
%%% font-size is 75% of the size of thumb height.
\newif\ifthumb
\newlength\thumbheight
\setlength\thumbheight{24pt}
\newlength\thumbedge
\setlength\thumbedge{4pt}
\newlength\thumbhspace
\setlength\thumbhspace{36pt}
\newlength\thumbvspace
\setlength\thumbvspace{2\thumbheight}

\newlength\thumbwidth
\setlength\thumbwidth{36pt}
\newlength\thumbspacing
\setlength\thumbspacing{2\thumbheight}

%% We need the TikZ library calc to calculate the coordinates of the thumb
%% indices.
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



\newcommand*\lthumb{%
    \ifthumb%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \
            \coordinate (top margin) at (0pt,1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep);
            \coordinate (left margin) at (0.95in+\evensidemargin,0pt);
            %% Calculate the corners of the thumb index based on the current
            %% chapter number.
            \coordinate (top left) at ($(current page.north west)-(top margin)-(0pt,\value{chapter}\thumbvspace-\thumbvspace)$);
            \coordinate (bottom right) at ($(top left)+(left margin)-(\thumbhspace,\thumbheight)$);
            %% Shift the left edge to prevent the rounded corner from showing.
            \coordinate (top left) at ($(top left)-(\thumbedge,0pt)$);

            %% Draw the thumb index.
            \fill[fill=thumb,rounded corners=\thumbedge](top left) rectangle (bottom right);
            %% Print the chapter number at the center right in the thumb index.
            \coordinate (center right) at ($(bottom right)+(0pt,0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \coordinate (rat center) at ($(bottom right)+(0.375in+0.375\evensidemargin-1.5mm, 0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \node at (center right)[anchor=east,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
                \titlefont\bfseries\color{tudelft-white}
                \fontsize{0.3\thumbheight}{0.3\thumbheight}\selectfont 
                \thechapter
            };
            \node at (rat center)[anchor=east,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{\includegraphics[width = 0.75in+0.75\evensidemargin]{Thumb/Rathead_lefft.jpg}};
            \node at (center right)[anchor=east,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
                \titlefont\bfseries\color{tudelft-white}
                \fontsize{0.75\thumbheight}{0.75\thumbheight}\selectfont
                \thechapter
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
}
%% rthumb draws a thumb index on the right (odd) page.
\newcommand*\rthumb{%
    \ifthumb%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \coordinate (top margin) at (0pt,1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep);
            \coordinate (right margin) at (0.95in+\evensidemargin,0pt);
            %% Calculate the corners of the thumb index based on the current
            %% chapter number.
            \coordinate (top right) at ($(current page.north east)-(top margin)-(0pt,\value{chapter}\thumbvspace-\thumbvspace)$);
            \coordinate (bottom left) at ($(top right)-(right margin)-(-\thumbhspace,\thumbheight)$);
            %% Shift the left right to prevent the rounded corner from showing.
            \coordinate (top right) at ($(top right)+(\thumbedge,0pt)$);
            %% Draw the thumb index.
            \fill[fill=thumb,rounded corners=\thumbedge](top right) rectangle (bottom left);
            %% Print the chapter number at the center right in the thumb index.
            \coordinate (center left) at ($(bottom left)+(0pt,0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \coordinate (center right rat) at ($(bottom left)+(-0.375in-0.375\evensidemargin+1.5mm,0.5\thumbheight)$);
            \node at (center right rat)[anchor = west, inner sep =2\thumbedge]{
            \includegraphics[width = 0.75in+0.75\evensidemargin]{Thumb/Rathead_right.jpg}
            };

            \node at (center left)[anchor=west,inner sep=2\thumbedge]{
                \titlefont\bfseries\color{tudelft-white}
                \fontsize{0.75\thumbheight}{0.75\thumbheight}\selectfont
                \thechapter
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi%
}
%% Page style for empty pages.
\fancypagestyle{empty}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
    \fancyhead{\cropmarks}
}

%% Page style for title pages.
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}
    \fancyhead{\cropmarks}
   % \fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\titlefont\thepage}
   }

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    %Page numbers outside
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\titlefont\thepage}


%FOR  the top RIGHT and top LEFT.
    \fancyhead[LE]{\cropmarks\lthumb\titlefont}
      \fancyhead[RO]{\cropmarks\rthumb\titlefont}

      %In the book class \leftmark is toplevel; \rightmark is subtoplevel
    %% Chapter name on the RIGHT (ODD) page.
    \fancyhead[LE]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    %% Section name on the LEFT (EVEN) page.
     \fancyhead[RO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase\rthumb{\rightmark}}
}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
%\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
%    \fancyhf{}
%    %% Page numbers on the top left and top right.
%    %%Removed ratheads to ensure faster execution
%    \fancyhead[lE]%{\cropmarks\lthumb\titlefont\thepage}%
%      \fancyhead[RO]{\cropmarks\rthumb\titlefont\thepage}
    %% Chapter name on the left (even) page.
%    \fancyhead[RE]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    %% Section name on the right (odd) page.
%     \fancyhead[LO]{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
%}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ \color{title}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{title}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{title}#1}{\color{title}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{title}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}

%% Draw the line above a footnote in the title color as well.
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{%
    \vspace*{-3pt}%
    {\color{title}\hrule width 0.5\textwidth height 0.4pt}%
    \vspace*{2.6pt}%
}

%% A part title starts with a huge (96pt) bold black number, flushed to the
%% right, followed by the part name on the next line in the title color.
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thepart}
    {0pt}
    {\huge\color{title}}
%% Separate the title from the text by two empty lines.
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
%% In the table of contents, the part name is preceded by an empty line, printed
%% in bold, and not followed by a line of dots.

%\dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}{<label width>}{<leaderwidth>}
% with <above-code> is code for the global formatting of the entry
% <left> sets the left margin from the left page margin.
% <label width> is the width of the space created for the label, as described above.
% <leaderwidth> breedte van de puntjes
\dottedcontents{part}[0em]{\vspace{\baselineskip}\titlefont\bfseries}{1.5em}{0pc}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\color{black}\Large\bf\filcenter}{}{0in}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{blue.png}}[]

%% Chapter titles have the same layout as parts.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\flushright\titlestyle}
    {\fontsize{96pt}{96pt}\selectfont\bfseries\thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\flushleft\Huge\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}
%% In the table of contents, a chapter is similar to a part, except that it is
%% preceded by half an empty line.
\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\vspace{1\baselineskip}\titlefont\bfseries}{1.5em}{0pc}

%% Section titles start with the number in bold, followed by the name printed
%% in the title color.
\titleformat{\section}
    {\Large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
%% Sections are preceded by an empty line.
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
%% In the table of contents, section names are followed by a line of dots 8pt
%% apart.
\dottedcontents{section}[4.7em]{\titlefont}{3.2em}{8pt}

%% Subsection titles have the same layout as section titles, except in a smaller
%% font.
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesubsection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
%% In the table of contents, subsection names are followed by a line of dots 8pt
%% apart.
\dottedcontents{subsection}[7.9em]{\titlefont}{3.2em}{8pt}


%%%ORIGINAL SETTINGS
%% Subsubsections have the same font and color as sections and subsections, but
%% are not preceded by a number.
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}
%    {\headerstyle}
%    {}
%    {0pt}
%    {\color{title}}
%% Subsubsections are preceded by an empty line and do not appear in the table
%% of contents.
%\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\bigskipamount}{0pt}

%%%%%MY version
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%% SubSubsection titles have the same layout as subsection titles, except in a smaller
%% font.
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesubsubsection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\dottedcontents{subsubsection}[7em]{\titlefont}{3.2em}{8pt}

%% paragraphs have the same font and color as sections and subsections, but
%% are not preceded by a number.
\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\large\headerstyle}
    {\bfseries\thesparagraph.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{title}}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\dottedcontents{paragraph}[7em]{\titlefont}{3.2em}{8pt}

%% Subsubsections are preceded by an empty line and do not appear in the table
%% of contents.
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{\bigskipamount}{0pt}


%% Color the bullets of the itemize environment and make the symbol of the third
%% level a diamond instead of an asterisk.
\renewcommand*\labelitemi{\color{title}\textbullet}
\renewcommand*\labelitemii{\color{title}--}
\renewcommand*\labelitemiii{\color{title}$\diamond$}
\renewcommand*\labelitemiv{\color{title}\textperiodcentered}

%% The dedication is vertically centered on a separate page and flushed to the
%% right.
\newcommand\dedication[1]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \begin{flushright}%
        #1%
    \end{flushright}%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \cleardoublepage%
}
\newcommand\publishedas[3][2\baselineskip]{%
    \begin{flushright}%
        {\itshape #2}%
        \vskip 0.5\baselineskip%
        #3%
    \end{flushright}%
    \vspace{#1}%
}%% Define an unnumbered footnote command.
\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}

%% The authors environment is used to display the authors of a chapter on the
%% title page. This is only necessary if multiple people contributed
%% significantly to the chapter.
\newcommand*\authors[1]{%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        {\Large\bfseries #1}%
    \end{flushleft}%
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}%
}

%% The epigraph environment can be used to to add a quote to the title page of
%% a chapter.
\newcommand\epigraph[3][2\baselineskip]{%
\vfill 
    \begin{flushright}%
        {\rmfamily\itshape #2}%
        \vskip 0.5\baselineskip%
        #3%
    \end{flushright}%
    \vspace{#1}%
}

%% The abstract environment is used for the abstract of a chapter.
\newenvironment{abstract1}{%
    \list{}{\leftmargin\rightmargin}%
    \item%
    \relax%
    \rmfamily\itshape%
}{%
    \endlist%
}

\newenvironment{abstract}{\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{flushleft} \topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}\small}{\vspace*{\fill}\end{flushleft}}


\newcommand{\LETTRINE}[2]{\lettrine{\LETTOverlock #1}{#2}}


%%Define an example box
%mybox
\newcounter{mybox}[chapter] \setcounter{mybox}{0}
\renewcommand{\themybox}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{mybox}}
\newenvironment{mybox}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{mybox}%

\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]
{\strut Box ~\themybox:~#1};},
innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=gray!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\newenvironment{mytablebox}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{mybox}%

\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray!20]
{\strut Box ~\themybox:~#1};},
innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=gray!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt,
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}










%%%%%EXAMPLE
%% \begin{mybox}[Optional Title]{box:label}
%%In a right triangle, the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the catheti.
%%\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
%%\end{mybox}
%%
%%


%% Define a drop command which can be used to generate drop caps at the
%% beginning of a section.

%\newcommand*\dropcap[2]{\lettrine[lines=2,findent=0.2em,nindent=0pt]{\color{title} #1}{#2}%}
%\font\Cal=cmsy10 at 25pt
%\def\pstart#1{\noindent\smash{\lower3ex\hbox{\llap{\Cal#1}}\hskip-.2em}
 % \parshape=3 1.5em \dimexpr\hsize-1.5em 2em \dimexpr\hsize-2em 0pt \hsize}
%\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\scshape}

%% Create an unnumbered reference section.
%\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\bibname{\color{title}References}}
%\newcommand*\references[1]{%
%    \bibliographystyle{dissertation}%
%    \bibliography{#1}%
%}

%% Hyperlinks are cyan, except in print mode, when they are all black.
%\hypersetup{
%    colorlinks = true,
%    citecolor = title,
%    linkcolor = title,
%    urlcolor = title
%}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{References}}

%Direct quotes in italics
\newcommand{\directquote}[1]{\enquote{\textit{#1}}}
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for the [`changepage`](https://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package?     `\usepackage[strict]{changepage} \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\stuffToDoOnOddPages\else\stuffToDoOnEvenPages\fi

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Andreas I was able to solve this using the `changepage` package

I defined a `\startchapter` command and changed the `openleft` setting of the bookclass to `openany`

```
\def\startchapter{%
    \clearpage%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage% 
        \thispagestyle{empty} %
        \phantom{emptypage}%
        \newpage%
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        \includegraphics{picture.pdf}%
    \else%
        \thispagestyle{empty} \includegraphics{picture.pdf}%

        \fi%
        }
```