# title chapter page

Tags: pagestyle

I am writing my thesis and I would like to have for each chapter a first fancy page with:
the title chapter and then a figure which represents a figurative table of contents and in the next page the conventional index of contents with the page numbers and so on..

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance,

Valentina[image]

Comment: For the table of contents in each chapter you could have a look at the `minitoc` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc

Comment: Which document class are you using? Could you please provide a minimal working example of what you came up with so far?

Comment: Without a document class, only guesses are possible.. But this question may be helpful: [How to make chapters start on odd pages with a picture on the even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422826)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
% memchaptocprob2.tex SE 538377

\documentclass[openleft]{memoir} % or book or report
%\documentclass[openleft]{book} % or book or report but they don't have openleft
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\clearpage
\minitoc
%\clearpage
\lipsum[1]
\section{One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

It requires the `minitoc` package for the local ToC; read the documentation (`texdoc minitoc`) as to how to change the appearance. The `memoir` class includes the `openleft` option so that chapters start on even numbered pages which your sample outputs indicates (if you use the `book` or `report` classes you will have to do some extra coding). It is up to you to provide the image and its location, and any other adjustments you feel you need, for example the relation between the local ToC and text.